# JS redirect function

Tags: javascript, function, include

I am trying to create a function that changes the redirect link of a button if the url contains the word "TicketPreDateable".
So I have a button like this one:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4" id="myproductid">
  <figure class="effect-product mx-auto"><img class="figure-img img-fluid" src="myimage">
    <figcaption><span class="badge badge-danger" style="top: -2.7em; background-color: red;">OFFRE SPÉCIALE</span>
      <h2 class="mt-0" style="color: white !important;"><span>My </span>Product Title</h2>
      <p>Profitez des pistes le samedi lorsque d'autres sont occupés à faire leurs valises ou coincés dans les bouchons. Un tarif unique à 24€ vous donne accès en toute liberté au domaine skiable pour la journée.</p>
      <a onclick="produrlmobile("https://www.mylink.com/fr/ProductsNgTicket/ticketPreDateable?poolNr=13&projNr=495&ticketTypeNr=122&preDatable=True&groupId=1&Day=11&Month=12&Year=2021")" href=""></a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

And my function look like this :

```js
function produrlmobile(produrl) {
  if (produrl.includes("TicketPreDateable")) {
    if (window.innerWidth < 960) {
      window.location.href = produrl.replace(
        "TicketPreDateable",
        "TicketPreDateableMobile"
      );
    } else {
      window.location.href = produrl;
    }
  } else {
    window.location.href = produrl;
  }
}
```

I have the impression that it is because of special characters in the url that the function does not work, but I do not know how to avoid that.

Thank you for your help and have a nice day !

Comment: it doesn't not work because it doesn't have a salary ... without joke be a little more explicite on the error you get or the problem you face.

Also the function produrlmobile take as string I think so you should send the url this way

```produrlmobile('https://www.mylink.com/fr/ProductsNgTicket/ticketPreDateable?poolNr=13&projNr=495&ticketTypeNr=122&preDatable=True&groupId=1&Day=11&Month=12&Year=2021)'``` I add simple qote

Comment: The function works perfectly with the simple quote, thank you very much for your answer
I will be more clear and explicit next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Sarens comment for issues with the HTML.

Also, note that the `replace` method is case sensitive. In your function it looks like you are trying to replace the string `TicketPreDateable`, but the url only contains `ticketPreDateable`.
I would recommend checking you are handling cases correctly, for both the old and new strings in the replace method arguments.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't see this error: I have to reread more carefully
With your and Sharen's solution, everything works perfectly, thank you very much!